# Simulate the inputs to get desired output from a Neural Network model in R

Tags: r, neural-networks

I have a **regression problem** at hand. There are **42 predictors**, a response variable and about 13000 rows in my data. All the attributes are **quantitative**.

I have built a neural network model using **nnet** which is doing quite well on the test set. I wanted to know if it is possible to simulate some of the inputs(say 4 out of 42) to maybe decrease/increase the value of the response variable and how to go about it in R. The exact quantitative inputs are not required but a range for those 4 predictors in which they can be varied to get the desired output.